# Access and Updates files on Ubuntu server from my Windows PC

Tags: windows, ubuntu, ftp, putty

I work in the data processing field which requires a lot of Computational power(CPU) and RAM.

**I currently have 2 PC:**

**Main PC (Windows) - Screen + GPU + Peripherals**

**Local Server (Ubuntu) - No Screen/GPU**

Both are connected to my router and i access the Server via putty and filezilla. I work primarily on my Main PC however and i have to keep a duplicate of the files, then every time i update something - i have to connect to filezilla - find the proper folder and update the file. Then run my process on the server which outputs in the browser on the main PC.

I am curious if there is a more efficient way to do this such as: Setting up a network drive on the Ubuntu server which i access from my windows pc and then update the files directly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Share the appropriate directories on the server with [Samba](https://www.samba.org/). How-to instructions are easily found with Google, for example [here](https://opensource.com/article/21/4/share-files-linux-windows) is an article from [opensource.com](https://opensource.com).

After that you can either mount the directories directly to your PC as any network drive and configure your application to work directly with the files on the network drive. In that case you won't have local copies of the files at all.

If you need to have local copies, find a backup solution for your PC. There are both paid and good freeware options. Personally I'd choose an option capable of plain old file / directory sync. You can again use google to learn about the options. If you want help in choosing the solution, you can drop a question to SE:s [Software Recommendations](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/) -site.

Answer (score 0):

One way is to bring windows to the linux world.
Try **SSHFS for Windows**, which you can find [here](https://github.com/winfsp/sshfs-win). This filesystem needs the underlying **Windows File System Proxy**, which you can find [here](https://github.com/winfsp/winfsp).

- First install the Windows File System Proxy
- Then intsall SSHFS for Windows

Now you can access any linux system simply by ssh.
You can map the linux machine by e.g.

```
net use y: \\sshfs\root@192.168.2.21
net use x: \\sshfs\root@host.example.com
```

This is the only working solution I found for ssh file access.